# Charging ignores TLP settings

Tags: power-management, battery, thinkpad, tlp

Thinkpad E430, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

I set the thresholds for charging to 85-93% in /etc/default/tlp , restarted the computer. Now it is at 99% and charging.

sudo tlp stat shows that it has successfully loaded the settings and prints the tresholds I set, but the battery is charging anyway. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [**FAQ**](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-faq.html):

> ## Why is my battery charged up to 100% – ignoring the charge thresholds?
>
> Possible causes are:
>
> ### Laptop is not a ThinkPad
>
> Battery charge thresholds and recalibration work with ThinkPads only.
>
> ### tp-smapi is not installed
>
> …
>
> ### Installation of package tp-smapi-dkms fails (Ubuntu)
>
> …
>
> ### Kernel module tp_smapi is not loaded
>
> Symptom: tlp-stat -b shows
>
> ```
> tp-smapi = inactive (kernel module 'tp_smapi' load error)
> ```
>
> Solution: try to load manually with
>
> ```
> sudo modprobe -v tp_smapi
> ```
>
> and check [tp-smapi Troubleshooting](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Tp_smapi#Troubleshooting) for a solution matching the error message or use adequate forums to resolve your issue with tp-smapi.
>
> tp-smapi does not support the following models:
>
> - ThinkPad SL300/400/500
> - ThinkPad X121e (AMD)
> - ThinkPad T430(s), T530, W530, X230 and all newer models – see according section below.
>
> …
>
> ### ThinkPad T420(s)/T520/W520/X220
>
> tp-smapi doesn't support start threshold and recalibration on Sandy Bridge generation ThinkPads. Symptoms are:
>
> tlp-stat -b shows
>
> ```
> /sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/start_charge_thresh = (not available)
> ```
>
> tlp setcharge or fullcharge shows the message
>
> ```
> start => Warning: cannot set threshold.
> ```
>
> tlp discharge or recalibrate show the message
>
> ```
> Error: discharge function not available for this ThinkPad model.
> ```
>
> Solution: TLP automatically uses tpacpi-bat when the kernel module acpi_call is available, see [Installation](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html#installation).
>
> ### ThinkPad T430(s)/T530/W530/X230 (or newer models)
>
> Solution: TLP automatically uses tpacpi-bat when the kernel module acpi_call is available, see [Installation](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html#installation).
>
> ### Battery has been removed
>
> By removing (and re-inserting) the battery the charge thresholds are reset to factory settings (96 / 100%). To restore TLP's settings the following two steps are needed:
>
> - Restart system
> - Shutdown and power off system
>
> or use
>
> ```
> sudo tlp setcharge
> ```
>
> See [Change Battery Charge Thresholds](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html#changethresholds).
>
> ## Charge thresholds shown by tlp-stat do not correspond to the configured ones
>
> Possible causes are:
>
> ### Configuration was not activated
>
> After changes to the configuration it is necessary to reboot. Alternatively use
>
> ```
> sudo tlp start
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> sudo tlp setcharge
> ```
>
> to activate the thresholds.
>
> ### ThinkPad Edge (E/S) series, L series, SL410/510
>
> On these models the threshold values shown by tlp-stat do not correspond to the written values. For example the setting START_CHARGE_THRESH_BATx=75 / STOP_CHARGE_THRESH_BATx=80 shows 75 / 74. The described behavior is caused by the firmware, not by TLP. Nonetheless the charge thresholds work as configured.

Comment: You are right, tp-smapi was not installed. Thanks

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness and clarity for all the ThinkPad users asking these questions, refer to this ThinkWiki page http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Tp_smapi#Model-specific_status to verify if your model is listed in tp_smapi feature support matrix.